# Enable Java Code Blocks folds in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

If I recall correctly it was possible to [fold codeblocks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding-2.html) (IFs, FORs, etc) in IntelliJ-Java but now I'm currently only able to fold entire functions.

[image]

Oddly enough I can fold codeblocks in `js` files.
[image]
*(moment.js fragment)*

Is possible to install a *plugin* or *enable a config* to add the codeblock level folding in Java?

I'm aware that I could use **custom folding regions** but that's **not** what I'm looking for.

Comment: have you checked the intellij documentation?

Comment: This one: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/folding-code-elements.html ? Which states: *Code folding works for the keywords if/ while/ else/for/ try/ except/finally/ with in case of at least two statements.*

Answer (score 1):

This is for IntelliJ 2017.2:

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding and
   enable "Custom folding regions"
2. Select the code to be folded
3. Go to Code -> Folding -> Fold Selection

Comment: I dont think that really helps if you have to explicitly define a custom folding region every time.

Comment: Yes, this would work but I was hopping for an automatic region detection like with the `JS` files.